# view controller on receiving push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I can successfully receive push notifications in my iOS app . My app  launch a Notification view controller when the notification  was received. However, and the notification ViewController is always there and i want to relaunch the app like it is the first time the app is opening . I use a tab bar controller . I use storyboard. The notification view controller doesn't have a relationship with the tab bar controller.

Comment: You don't want the Notification view controller to show if the application was in background ?

Comment: what i want is to exit the notification view controller once is viewed